# Can anyone tell me how to typecast a U64 variable to U16 and pass by reference to function? I don't want to pass it as pointer

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference

For example, consider below c++ code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;
typedef unsigned long long u64;
typedef unsigned short u16;

void call(u16& c)
{
    cout<<"\nc: "<<hex<<c;
    c=0x2323;   
}

int main() {
    u64 c1=0x12345678;
    call(c1);
    cout<<"\nc1: "<<hex<<c1;
    return 0;
}
```

Compilation Error: invalid initialization of reference of type 'u16& {aka short unsigned int&}' from expression of type 'u64 {aka long long unsigned int}'

Comment: You can't do it.

Comment: If a reference to `u16` is expected you have to use a variable of type `u16`. Please note, that `0x12345678` doesn't fit into a 16 bit type.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? Is like putting a round block in a square hole. What's the actually problem you are trying to solve and why?

Comment: Yes, i'm aware that u64 value will be truncated to u16 so it will contain only 0x5678. I want to both typecast and pass-by-reference at the same time. Is there a way to do or simply i have to pass it as pointer to achieve this.

Comment: I know it below will work but dont want to do this way

void call(u16* c)
{
 cout<<"\nc: "<<hex<<*c;
 *c=0x2323; 
}

int main() {
 u64 c1=0x12345678;
 call((u16*)&c1);
 cout<<"\nc1: "<<hex<<c1;
    return 0;
}

Comment: @Orangekishor if the compiler were to create a temporary u16 value and pass a reference to that (truncated) value into `call()`, then the value that `call()` writes `0x2323` to would be inaccessible to the calling code, and therefore `call()` would have no effect on anything.

Comment: Accessing only parts of a number is tricky to do correctly, even with pointers, as you could get into *undefined behavior* or *strict aliasing* territory. So I agree with those other comments, which ask, what do you actually want to do?

Answer (score 1):

Since a `u64` has four times the number of bits in it as a `u16`, the only way to get it to fit is to chop it up into four pieces and feed them through one at a time, and then reassemble them all back together on the other side, like a sectional sofa:

```
u64 c1=0x12345678;
u16 firstPart = (u16)(c1 & 0xFFFF);
call(firstPart);
u16 secondPart = (u16)((c1>>16) & 0xFFFF);
call(secondPart);
u16 thirdPart = (u16)((c1>>32) & 0xFFFF);
call(thirdPart);
u16 fourthPart = (u16)((c1>>48) & 0xFFFF);
call(fourthPart);
c1 = ((u64)firstPart)        |
     (((u64)secondPart)<<16) |
     (((u64)thirdPart)<<32)  |
     (((u64)forthPart)<<48);
```

Update:  a more serious answer, based on details in the comments:

```
void call(u16& c)
{
   cout<<"\nc: "<<hex<<c;
   c=0x2323;   
}

// wrapper function to allow passing u64s in.
// The least significant 16 bits of the u64 will be modified by call(u16&)
void call(u64& c)
{
   u16 lowBits = (u16)(c&0xFFFF);
   call(lowBits);
   c &= ~((u64)(0xFFFF));
   c |= (u64)lowBits;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jeremy Friesner, like this only i expected.